# Regex Expressions, URL and end part

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex expression to detect a URL with a dynamic ending from a message. So for example it would be something like this.

"http://loclhost/something/randomstring example text example text example text"

So the "http://localhost/something/" will always be the same but the random string part wont and I want to grab "http://loclhost/something/randomstring" only...

I've tried doing this expression

"/http://localhost/something/(.*) "

The thing is, it selects the whole text. I've tried looking up online but can't find anything. Would love some help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` will keep 'eating up' characters. You probably want something like

```
/http:\/\/localhost\/something\/([^\s]*)/
```

to make it 'stop' at a white-space character. Or

```
/http:\/\/localhost\/something\/([a-z0-9]*)/
```

if you are sure that `randomstring` only contains alpha-numerical characters.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/U12o53/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `(.*)` part of the url so it only contains valid url characters, e.g.

```
/http:\/\/localhost\/something\/([\d\w\-_]*)/
```

You can modify it as you need based on the characters that can be in randomstring.